# liip_imagine [ inside Sylius] not caching images on linux

Tags: php, symfony, sylius, liipimaginebundle

**Sylius version affected**:

### Latest

**Description**

Hello i'm trying to set up my firt e-commerce App with sylius, and that not easy with documentation.
So, i will create a new product with admin panel, product will be create with success, but if i return to the shop the first images will be cached by liip ( that really cool, Thank you Sylius ! ), i click on my product for enter on it but if i'm inside the new created product, the product images will be not cached.
I have trying to cache manually but that not work, i only have the same error : cannot resolve cache from root but i not specify the root path i only specify the path to image like this → images/******.jpg
**Steps to reproduce**

- >Full install Sylius and try to create a new product.

**Possible Solution**

I don't know this bug it's the 2nd time liip_imagine does this to me.
Thank you for any one want to help you are my sun :sun_with_face:

Comment: Can you share the code where you render the images?

Comment: Hello that’s an old post I’m on laravel now and everything work thank you :)